# Static field initializer is not called in Windows Phone 8 C# app

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, static-initialization

I have a static class with a static field that is initialized in place:

```
private static SomeType _instance = new SomeType();
```

This code is a part of a portable class library that is used on multiple platforms. Everything works fine on desktop platforms, but when compiled for Windows Phone 8 the _instance is null. But if I move the initialization to a default static constructor, the _instance is initialized properly.

I tried to search for an explanation of this behavior but haven't found anything that would explain it.

**UPDATE**. I spent some time trying to create a repeatable sequence of steps to reproduce the error, but at some point error no longer occurred even when I switched back to the original code. I came to conclusion that this was a false alarm and the problem was apparently caused by something else. I don't feel comfortable to leave it without explanation, but so far I have no grounds to believe that this has to do with static field initialization.

Comment: Might actually be a bug, have you tried raising a Connect ticket for it?

Comment: I guess it might have been set to `null` somewhere. Just add `readonly` keyword and see issue is still there?

Comment: Spent more time on it. Didn't manage to create a repeatable scenario. Most likely this was a false alarm. If this happens again, I will update the post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the order of static class initialization in C# deterministic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681055/is-the-order-of-static-class-initialization-in-c-sharp-deterministic)

Comment: Vagif, have you tried @Sriram's suggestion? If you add readonly you will immediately get a compiler error if there is any other code that could possibly change the value of the field.

Comment: Also, you have not written *where* in your code you evaluated the field and got `null`. Could it be in a static field initializer or a static constructor? If so, @Eugene's link might be relevant.

Comment: @chiccodoro, yes I tried Sriram's suggestion. As I wrote in the update to the post, I can no longer reproduce the error and came to the conclusion that this was a false alarm.

Comment: Does that static field must be initialized during a deserialization process ? Because for example DataContractSerializer doesn't pass by the construction process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that nothing else is updating the static value, as static properties will get initialized as the app domain is created.