# Static Objects Are Null/Not Initialized At Correct time

Tags: c#, .net, enums, static, .net-micro-framework

I am using the [type-safe enum pattern](http://blog.falafel.com/introducing-type-safe-enum-pattern/) outlined here. I have a need to nest one type-safe enum into another. The child property(static object) is NULL at the time the parent constructor is created. It seems like the child constructor is not called and I'm getting some errors.(parent and child my be confusing, but it explains the hierarchy)

Here's an example(I'm using netMF):

```
public class MyDeviceSetting //parent
{
        public readonly string Name;
        public MyUnit SettingUnit;
        public readonly MyUnit.UnitPurpose UnitPurpose;

          #region MY STATIC SETTINGS
        //UNIT SETTINGS
        public static MyDeviceSetting TempUnits = new MyDeviceSetting("TempUnits", MyUnit.mm); //MyUnit.mm is null. Why?
        public static MyDeviceSetting BLAH = new MyDeviceSetting("BLAH", MyUnit.inch);//MyUnit.inch is null. Why?
          #endregion



        /// <summary>
        /// This is the MAIN PRIVATE Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="?"></param>
        private MyDeviceSetting(string name, MyUnit defaultUnit)
        {
            Name = name;
            SettingUnit = defaultUnit;//NULL
            UnitPurpose = SettingUnit.Purpose; //fails because SettingUnit is NULL


        }


    }


public sealed class MyUnit
{
    private static int Count = 0;

    //these are used to store and identify the unit in memory
    public readonly int UnitID;
    public readonly int TestID;

    public enum UnitPurpose
    {
        DISTANCE,
        SPEED,
        TEMPERATURE,
        TIME,
        CLOCK,
        NO_UNITS
    }

    public readonly string DisplayName;
    public readonly string Abbreviation;
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly UnitPurpose Purpose;

    #region My Units
    public static readonly MyUnit mm = new MyUnit("Milimeters", "mm", "mm", UnitPurpose.DISTANCE, 1);
    public static readonly MyUnit inch = new MyUnit("inch", "inch", "in", UnitPurpose.DISTANCE, 2);



    #endregion

    private MyUnit(string name,
                   string displayName,
                   string abbreviation,
                   UnitPurpose unitPurpose,
                   int unitID)
    {
        Name = name;
        DisplayName = displayName;
        Abbreviation = abbreviation;
        Purpose = unitPurpose;
        UnitID = unitID;
        TestID = Count;
        Count++;

    }


}
```

How do I ensure that `child` is NOT null? Is there a work-around? Edit: [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681055/is-the-order-of-static-class-initialization-in-c-sharp-deterministic) ensures that this should just work, but in my case it's not working.
[image: Null]

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't compile, but after making the trivial changes required to make it compile, it works fine. Please provide a short but complete example which actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll try to extract an example from the real code - I fixed the current code

Comment: I would try using a static constructor in each class and initialize each static enum values in there

Comment: Why ParentEnum and ChildEnum have private constructors? there's no way to instantiate them.

Comment: @JuanK It is the purpose of being an *Enum*

Comment: @JuanK check the link in the first sentence of my question. No need to instantiate it.

Comment: It looks probable to me that there's an initialization dependency cycle between the two classes in your actual code.

Comment: I'm with Jon Skeet here.  I run your code and it works.  The `Child` field of the `ParentEnum` are not `null`.

Comment: @zneak only the Parent has a reference to the child...I was looking for that. Unless I'm missing a concept here

Comment: @juharr Yes, this example seems to work, but my real code does not. I am trying to update my example to exhibit this issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated the example code and and it exhibits this issue.

Comment: @zneak The update example code exhibits the issue I describe

Comment: Might want to update the peripherals around the code too; there's no `child` in there, so I can't begin to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: @GusMofx I have tested you're last updated code, but everything looks ok, the code you tell us must fail or resulting in null... is working fine. :S

Comment: Your example doesn't have a `Main` method for us to run - and you really need to cut it down to *just* what you need to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: So you appear to think the issue is that `SettingUnit` is null.  You also seem to be saying that `defaultUnit` is null and in your code you set `SettingUnit = defalutUnit`.  So `SettingUnit` is null because you set it to null.  So either you question is why is a variable I set to null now null, which is nonsense, or there is something else missing from your question.

Comment: @shf301, `defaultUnit` is passed into the constructor. The defaultUnit is a static object from the child type-safe enum.

Comment: @GisMofx Someone's passing null into the constructor.  I don't know why because you are not showing us that code.

Comment: @shf301 The constructor in `MyUnit` doesn't seem to get called before the constructor in `MyDeviceSetting` All the code is there.

Comment: Use the stack to see which call to the constructor is passing `null` and show that line of code.

Comment: @juharr In my example the two lines beneath `//UNIT SETTINGS` . `MyUnit.mm` and `MyUnit.inch` are NULL.

Comment: Your latest example works fine for me.  Either there is some important piece missing or there is something weird going on in your setup.  Have you tried doing a Rebuild before debugging?

Comment: @juharr I'm deploying a netMF application, not a console app.  When I step through the code, `MyDeviceSetting` members get initialized before `MyUnit` members.

Comment: In that case this sounds like it might be a bug with netMF.  You should mention that in the question and add a tag for it.

Comment: I'm investigating if it's a netMF issue. Otherwise, is there a possible work-around?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug/limitation of the .Net Micro framework.  It doesn't fully support static constructors.  Here's someone who is reporting the same issue:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc533032.aspx

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc533032.aspx) for NetCF 3.0 contains the following warning:

> Do not use static constructors. They are not yet fully supported by the .NET Micro Framework.

From this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sandeepp/archive/2005/10/04/static-constructors.aspx) also seems to say that (at least as of 2.0) calls to static constructors were serialized:

> There are some things that cannot be done in .NET Compact Framework in
>   a static constructor which are possible in the full .NET Framework.
>   Basically, all static constructors when are executed in a serialized
>   fashion in .NET Compact Framework V2

That post discusses it in the context of deadlocks, but I believe it is the reason this isn't working.

Unfortunately for that means you can't rely on the statics and will have to handle initialization and locking yourself.  Something like this should work:

```
private static MyUnit inch;

public static MyUnit Inch
{
    get
    {
        if (inch == null)
            inch = new MyUnit("inch", "inch", "in", UnitPurpose.DISTANCE, 2);
         return inch;
    }
}
```

This unfortunately looses the thread safety that a static constructor gave you.  That will be hard to fix since you can't rely on a static members since as we've seen you can't rely on them being initialized.

Comment: **_calls to static constructors were serialized:_** Interesting. I was inspired to rename `MyUnit` to `MyAUnit` and it seems the initialization is ordered alphabetically/alphanumerically/whatever. Now it calls those constructors before and I no longer get NULL runtime errors!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can move `MyUnit` class to another source file called MyUnit.cs, this will cause .netmf CLR load this class at first.

I have already tested in my environment running .Netmf 4.3 RTM.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is very difficult to replicate, any way one needs to be pragmatic.

You can made `MyUnit` static field to be initialized prior to `MyDeviceSetting` static fields just calling `MyUnit` at first.

And that's pretty easy ,just create a dummy variable before any other thing on your program.

```
public class MyDeviceSetting //parent
{
    static MyDeviceSetting()
    {
        var dummy = MyUnit.inch;
    }
}
```

So, dummy var is never used but the static instance of MyUnit is initialized.

After that any activity with `MyDeviceSetting` will get `MyUnit` initialized.

Comment: I tried. It still initializes after the Parent class.

Comment: This shouldn't be happen. Where are you creating the dummy var? Just do it in the first line of code executed once your program is launched.

Comment: @GisMofx I have modified the code putting the dummy var in MyDeviceSetting  new static constructor. Static constructor + dummy initialization should work.

Comment: Are you able to try with netMF?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86836/discussion-between-juank-and-gismofx).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @shf301 with the reasoning why it's not working correctly, It seems that the constructors are called in some type of alphabetical/alphanumerical order when compiled.

Renaming the Child Class to `MyAUnit`makes it come before `MyDeviceSetting` and seems to trigger `MyAUnit` static members before `MyDeviceSetting`static memebers.

This seems to work, yet somewhat of a "hack" for the time being.