# Lazy Property Initialization in static class C#

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation

I have been given this code

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static Func<ILogger> LoggerFactory;
    private static readonly Lazy<ILogger> _log = new Lazy<ILogger>(LoggerFactory);

    public static ILogger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _log.Value;
        }
        public static ILogger ConfigureLogging(string AppName, Version AppVersion)
        {
             // stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This static class is used in the application:

```
Logger.LoggerFactory = () => Logger.ConfigureLogging(AppName, AppVersion);
Logger.Instance.Information("Starting application");
```

I would expect the first row to set the LoggerFactory; however on the first attempt of writing to the log, an exception has thrown because the static Func LoggerFactory hasn't been set yet.

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: Because when you create `_log`, `LoggerFactory` is null. By the time you do `Logger.LoggerFactory = ...` you've already initialized `_log`

Comment: You could try: `private static readonly Lazy<ILogger> _log = new Lazy<ILogger>(() => LoggerFactory());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quick and dirty fix for this would be to do this:

```
private static readonly Lazy<ILogger> _log = new Lazy<ILogger>(() => LoggerFactory());
```

`Lazy` takes a function that will be executed when you first try to access the `Value`, but in your code you are passing it `null` because you haven't yet initialized `LoggerFactory`. The static initializer in your class will run before the first time any of the static fields are accessed, so your attempt to access `LoggerFactory` will trigger your `_log` field to initialize (if it hasn't already) at which point `LoggerFactory` is null. See, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3681278/1250301) for some discussion on static initialization.

You can defer accessing `LoggerFactory` but wrapping it in a function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the execution order:

```
private static readonly Lazy<ILogger> _log = new Lazy<ILogger>(null);
//LoggerFactory is null at this point

Logger.LoggerFactory = () => Logger.ConfigureLogging(AppName, AppVersion);
Logger.Instance.Information("Starting application");
```

and thus _log will stay as null

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I understand the exec order.