# Tips for terser field initialization in C#

Tags: c#, initialization

I'm getting up to speed in C#; my experience is with C++ and Java. I wonder if there's a trick I can use to reduce "stuttering" (repeating the same code in multiple places) when declaring and initializing some related fields?

Here's a trivial example of what I'd like to do (using the [UrhoSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/urho/) 3D library):

```
public class MyScene
{
    Scene scene = new Scene();
    Node camera = scene.CreateChild("Camera");
    Node light = scene.CreateChild("Light");
    Node model = scene.CreateChild("Model");

    // etc
}
```

However, this doesn't compile because the `Node` field initializers "cannot reference the non-static field" `scene`. The simplest solution would seem to be:

```
public class MyScene2
{
    Scene scene = new Scene();
    Node camera, light, model;

    MyScene2()
    {
        camera = scene.CreateChild("Camera");
        light = scene.CreateChild("Light");
        model = scene.CreateChild("Model");
    }

    // etc
}
```

For every one extra `Node`, <del>I need two extra lines of code</del> I need to edit two lines of code. *(Edit: collapsed the declarations into one line per Gusman's suggestion)* Is there any technique I can use to make this terser?

In recent versions of C++, the first code snippet would work -- fields are initialized in strict order and can refer to previous fields. In Java, I could put `scene` in an outer class and have the `Node` fields in an inner class so they can refer to it, but C# doesn't have the same notion of inner classes. (Of course, I don't mean to say those languages are "better", they're just different and I'm more familiar with them.)

For this specific example I could maybe have `MyScene` inherit from `Scene`, but I'm very wary of introducing inheritance just to make the code shorter! And I might need a more complex tree of nodes, rather than everything being a direct child of `scene`. So I wonder if there's anything that can be done purely at the field initialization level.

Comment: `Node camera, light, model;` a bit of code reduction :)

Comment: Doh, yes! Good idea, helps a bit.

Comment: I'd personally question why you're doing so much work in the constructor. Maybe you need a `MySceneFactory` that goes and sets up the child nodes for the scene, and then injects each of those fields' values into the `MyScene` constructor. More lines of code, but better separation of concerns.

Comment: I don't think it's really a lot of work, it's creating four objects in a simple tree hierarchy. Four lines of code for those four things seems ideal to me, especially if the fields can be `readonly`.

Comment: Is an "inner class" in Java different from a [nested class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx) in C#?

Comment: In Java an inner class is always associated with an instance of the outer class (i.e. you get an implicit "outer" as well as implicit "this"). You need to declare the class `static` to make it a nested class like C++ or C#.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: you can get the desired terseness using properties and [expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#more-expression-bodied-members).

```
sealed class MyScene2
{
    public Scene scene => new Scene();
    public Node camera => scene.CreateChild("Camera");
    public Node light => scene.CreateChild("Light");
    public Node model => scene.CreateChild("Model");
}
```

However, his code will call `CreateChild()` every time the property is accessed.

The most succinct I've been able to come up with so far for one-time field initialization is using C# 7's tuples:

```
public class MyScene
{
    static (Scene, Node, Node, Node) f(Scene scene)
    {
        return (scene, scene.CreateChild("Camera"), scene.CreateChild("Light"), scene.CreateChild("Model"));
    }
    readonly (Scene scene, Node camera, Node light, Node model) t2 = f(new Scene());
};
```

that's only one line longer ...

Comment: This seems to increase the stuttering -- "camera" (or "c") is now used 6 times on 3 different lines.

Comment: Oh, neat! That's exactly the sort of thing I want to learn about. Sounds like it would run that expression every time the property is accessed, though? If so it doesn't work for the problem as stated, where the member variable needs to be initialized just once.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, C++/CLI *does* support the "terse" syntax:

```
ref struct MyScene
{
    Scene^ scene = gcnew Scene();
    Node^ camera = scene->CreateChild("Camera");
    Node^ light = scene->CreateChild("Light");
    Node^ model = scene->CreateChild("Model");
};
```

you can even add `initonly` ("`readonly`" from C#) to each field.

Answer (score 0):

If terseness is your primary concern and you expect to have to initialize a bunch of private fields in the same way, why not do something like this:

```
public class Scenery {
    Dictionary<String, Node> children = new Dictionary<String, Node> {
              {"Camera", null}, {"Light", null}, {"Model", null}};

    Scene scene = new Scene();

    public Scenery() {
        foreach (var s in children.Keys) {
            children[s] = scene.CreateChild(s);
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to easily add or subtract fields as needed.

Comment: This makes it harder to access the nodes afterwards. Rather than having a named field containing the Node you want, you'd have to keep pulling it out of the dictionary.

Comment: True but the dictionary is very fast and the intent is always clear (ie children["Camera"].DoSomething()).  If it really bothered you could provide getters 'Node Camera { get { return children["Camera"]; } }', but that works against terseness.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example using nested classes to achieve what you want.

```
public  class ShinyClass
{
    class InnerVar
    {
        public static Random r = new Random();
    }

    decimal d1 = InnerVar.r.Next();
    decimal d2 = InnerVar.r.Next();
    decimal d3 = InnerVar.r.Next();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return d1 + " " + d2 + " " + d3;
    }
}
```

Update:
There is a gotcha moment here. If you change the value of the variables in the inner class, their static nature will affect all ShinyClass objects. So if you make r null somewhere for instance, and then another method tries to use it in a different object, this won't work. So if you add something like this to my ShinyClass above:

```
public void KillRandom()
{
    InnerVar.r = null;
}

public int UseVar()
{
    return InnerVar.r.Next();
}
```

And then you try and do something like this:

```
var s = new ShinyClass().ToString();

new ShinyClass().KillRandom();

var e = new ShinyClass().UseVar();
```

`s` will be a valid result, but trying to get `e` will throw a NullReferenceException.
In that case, this method won't help.

Comment: The `static` is a bit scary! Are there guarantees on exactly when it gets initialized? On first reference to `InnerVar`?

Comment: Here's a good link to when statics are initialized -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/3681278/1193647.  The short (and probably not 100% correct) answer is C# will initialize the variable before first use.