# Why is the method returning in yield return get.SendWebRequest()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function in unity that makes a request for a server, and for each value in the result, it should call a function to add a image on a list and get an object from the same server and add on another list

```
    public void SaveServer() {
        string serverAddress = inputField.text;
        GlobalStateData.getInstance().ServerAdress = serverAddress;
        StartCoroutine(Utils.GetRequest(GlobalStateData.getInstance().ServerAdress + "file/ObjectController/",
            (UnityWebRequest) => {
                JArray jsonResponse = JArray.Parse(UnityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                foreach (var json in jsonResponse) {
                    String base64 = (string)json["trackingImage"]["file"]["base64"];
                    String name = (string)json["file"]["name"];
                    int objectId = (int)json["id"];
                    Texture2D texture = Utils.Base64ToTexture2D(base64);

                    StartCoroutine(addImageAndObject(objectId, texture, name));
                }
                Debug.Log(jsonResponse);
                transform.parent.Find("canvas_MainMenu").gameObject.SetActive(true);
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }));
    }

    private IEnumerator addImageAndObject(int objectId, Texture2D texture2D, String name) {
        StartCoroutine(addImage(texture2D, name));
        yield return AddObjectById(objectId, name).MoveNext();
    }
```

but in the AddObjectById the method is stopping before complete the request

```
    private IEnumerator AddObjectById(int id, string name) {
        string url = GlobalStateData.getInstance().ServerAdress + "bundle/ObjectBundleController/" + id;
        
        UnityWebRequest get = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return get.SendWebRequest(); // it stops here
        if (get.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) {
            Debug.Log(get.error);
            yield return false;
        }
        else {
            AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(get);
            GameObject obj = (GameObject)bundle.LoadAsset(name);
            _place3DObjectRef.ArPrefabs.Add(obj);   
            yield return true;
        }
    }
```

I didn't understand how my **GetRequest** Method Works and the **AddObjectById**

Here is the GetRequest

```
    public static IEnumerator GetRequest(string server, Action<UnityWebRequest> successCallback, Action<String> errorCallback = null) {
        UnityWebRequest get = UnityWebRequest.Get(server);
        yield return get.SendWebRequest();
        if (get.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) {
            Debug.Log(get.error);
            if(errorCallback != null)
                errorCallback("Cannot make request to " + server +
                          "\nerror:" + get.error);
            yield return false;
        }
        else {
            successCallback(get);
            yield return true;
        }
    }
```

and this one runs fine.
What should I do to the method to not stops after the first yield return?

EDIT:
I solved the problem!
The reason why this was happening, it was because the gameObject was setting deactivated before the coroutine finishes, so the scripts was stopping

`gameObject.SetActive(false);`

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html
The unity documentation says that "Deactivating a GameObject disables each component, including attached renderers, colliders, rigidbodies, and scripts. For example, Unity will no longer call the Update() method of a script attached to a deactivated GameObject. OnEnable or OnDisable are called as the GameObject received SetActive(true) or SetActive(false)." So, as the script is an component attached to the scene object, makes sense that it stops working

Comment: Id avoid using a variable of get which is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if the gameObject is not active `gameObject.SetActive(false);` the Coroutines stops too. The problem was not with the coroutines but with the gameObject being deactivated

Answer (score 1):

Well, `yield`  works by returning results from one iteration,and what comes after will not be executed. In your method, when a call is made to `AddObjectById`, **it will stop at the first  `yield`** it finds and return its value, in this case `get.SendWebRequest();`, **not continuing the flow.** If you move `yield return get.SendWebRequest();`  after of `if-else`, it will never enter, as it will have some return in `yield return`  coming from "if-else".

Comment: but how does the "GetRequest" works? it use the yield return in the same place

Comment: Because of static class initialization order in C#. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681055/is-the-order-of-static-class-initialization-in-c-sharp-deterministic