# Convert DirectoryInfo to String in Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, directoryinfo

I am trying to write a project Windows Service in C#.

I wanna copy folder to another directory. I wrote the codes, everything is perfect

```
DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\belgeler");
DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\Backup");
```

This is correct implementation,but when i write this...

```
DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(from_path);
DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(to_path);
```

> The error is 'A field initializer cannot reference the non-static
>   field,method or property 'BACKUP(myproject_name).Service1.veri'

```
//string to_path = Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue("ToPath").ToString();  
//string from_path = Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue("FromPath").ToString();
```

This code block is working console application but in windows service it is not.

Comment: Is it a non-static field, method, or property? ;)

Comment: "This code block is working console application but in windows service it is not." It's COMPILING as a console app, but not as a windows service? I highly doubt that...

Comment: Is `from_path` and `to_path` members of your class, or are they local variables?  What about `source` or `target` ?

Comment: ok i solved it.
To able to implement,it would be in method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables `source` and `target` are member variables of your class.  The following code is allowed:

```
DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\belgeler");
DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\Backup");
```

It is permitted because it is not referencing any other member variables of your class.  But when you try:

```
DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(from_path);
DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(to_path);
```

This references other variables `from_path` and `to_path` which is not permitted.

Move these variables to be local variables and that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a field's value using another field as a parameter, you just need to do it in the constructor.   This will ensure that the fields are set in the proper order.

[A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)