# Trying to multiply the input from a text box and show the result on a label, but getting an error

Tags: c#

```
    decimal aPrice = 15.75m;

    decimal aSales = decimal.Parse(txtASales.Text);

    decimal aRev = (aPrice * aSales);

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblARev.Text = aRev.ToString();
    }
```

This is the code i have for it, what I'm trying to do is multiply the price of A-type tickets and the number of A-type tickets sold.  The number sold will be taken from the user in a text box "txtASales" which I got from the object window, and renamed in the properties window (no coding done for that).  Then the revenue will be shown on a label "lblARev".  I am getting an error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" for txtASales, aPrice, and aSales.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference txtASales, aPrice or aRev outside of a method that you create or one of the .NET events. You could do this:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal aPrice = 15.75m;

    decimal aSales = decimal.Parse(txtASales.Text);

    decimal aRev = (aPrice * aSales);

    lblARev.Text = aRev.ToString();
}
```

But you cannot reference non-static(txtSales, aPrice, aRev) at the class level if they are not static from a field initializer.