# failed to initialize DTE object

Tags: envdte

I am following a code sample in [this](http://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_automationinterface/36028797261685771.html&id=) link.

I hit a snag right on the second line:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using EnvDTE;

namespace TwinCAT_Automation_Interface
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Creating TwinCAT Projects via templates (Recommended)
        Type        myType  =   System.Type     .GetTypeFromProgID  ("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
        dynamic     myDTE   =   System.Activator.CreateInstance     (myType);  //error right here
    }
}
```

The error says:

> Error 1   A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'TwinCAT_Automation_Interface.Main.myType'

What exactly am I doing wrong? It's the same code snippet; I just modify it a bit.  Please help!!!!

OK, I got it fixed by changing it to the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using EnvDTE;

namespace TwinCAT_Automation_Interface
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void myMethod()
        {
            //Creating TwinCAT Projects via templates (Recommended)
            Type        myType  =   System.Type     .GetTypeFromProgID  ("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
            dynamic     myDTE   =   System.Activator.CreateInstance     (myType);                   // dynamic linking for DTE-object
        }
    }
}
```

The explanation is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property) link.  It is a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

It is a compiler error.  See question for link to the answer.