# In the body of a class, why does field initialization work but method calls don't?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, why doesn't field initializer syntax not throw compilation errors, however, method calls do? For example,

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    void SomeMethod() { }
}

class SomeClass {

    SomeOtherClass someOtherObject = new SomeOtherClass();
    someOtherObject.SomeMethod();
}
```

Why does the someOtherObject initialization, which essentially is a constructor call work? My understanding is that a constructor is also a method. However the second line, where there is a method call, does not work. Is this a language design choice?

Comment: A class is just a skeleton, it can not on its own perform operations/action. Assume suppose it is allowed then simply you don't have control over the class behavior i.e. you don't have a way to do a set of operations as and when required in a controlled manner. But it is perfectly fine to invoke methods/actions from within constructor so that class instantiation itself can do some basic stuff for you. + OOPS (object orientation)!! Hope you get it..

Comment: + Check [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)

Comment: Right, that clears it up a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SomeOtherClass someOtherObject = new SomeOtherClass();
```

is syntactic sugar for this anyway:

```
SomeOtherClass someOtherObject;

public SomeClass() {
    someOtherObject = new SomeOtherClass()
}
```

So nothing is executed outside of the constructor. The compiler will create an empty constructor if it doesn't exist and initialize *someOtherObject*.

Answer (score 0):

A Class contains **attributes** and **methods** **declarations** and **definitions** only. Attributes can be initialized right there as you're doing

```
SomeOtherClass someOtherObject = new SomeOtherClass();
```

and in the constructors.

Doing

```
someOtherObject.SomeMethod();
```

is neither declaration/definition nor initialization. Which is not allowed.

Comment: **Why** is it not allowed?

Comment: When will the compiler run this line? This is neither in Main nor you can invoke it anywhere.

Comment: Right. So, applying the same logic, shouldn't the constructor call also not be allowed. The constructor call is also a method call.

Comment: As mentioned, initialization is allowed because the compiler needs to initialize every member (attributes) so it'll call its constructors to initalize it when an object of class is created. But there is no way someOtherObject.SomeMethod(); will be called.