# a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field

Tags: c#

I have no idea why this isn't working

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Button[,] button = new Button[3, 3]{ {button1, button2, button3 },
                                                 {button4, button5, button6 },
                                                 {button7, button8, button9 } };
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I get the error

> a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field

on all 9 Buttons

Comment: These buttons have to be referenced from static fields. This is what the compiler is telling you. If you don't like this, initialize `button` from the constructor.

Comment: See this for an explanation why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property

Answer (score 3):

A field initializer (as the error clearly states) can not reference nonstatic fields or values. `button1` to `button9` are not static. To achieve the same result, move your array initialization in the constructor of your form:

```
private Button[,] button;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    button = new Button[3, 3]{ {button1, button2, button3 },
                                {button4, button5, button6 },
                                {button7, button8, button9 } };
}
```