# Can this immutable property be converted to an auto property?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I've been going through an app I'm developing and it makes heavy use of immutability. I've just discovered getter-only automatic properties are in C# 6.0 so I'm refactoring to use those. I've hit one possible question-mark though, which is where I'm exposing `private IList<T>` objects as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` through public properties, to avoid the possibility of them being casted back to their original `List<T>` object, e.g.

`private IList<string> tags = new List<string>();`

`public IEnumerable<string> Tags => new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(this.tags);`

Is there any way to use auto-properties with this type of customised getter?

Comment: It can't be an auto-property because you have code in the getter. The question is what is wrong? Why do you need an auto-property?

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be an auto-property, I just wondered if it could be - to align with the general code style.

Comment: *"with the general code style"* - there is no such thing as using only auto-properties or only full properties. Btw, calling getter only property *immutable* feels wrong if it expose **new instance** of something every time. Consider to initialize that property in constructor and then you indeed can use auto property (with getter only).

Comment: @Sinatr: I have taken the liberty to include (and flesh out) your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Auto-properties are a shortcut for properties which *don't* have customized getters or setters.

---

As a side note: As Sinatr correctly mentions in the comments, you are creating a new instance of the ReadOnlyCollection on every property invocation. That is untypical for a property. Consider returning the same instance every time instead:

```
private IList<string> tags = new List<string>();
public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; }

public MyClass()
{
    Tags = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(this.tags);
}
```

This works because `ReadOnlyCollection` reflects changes made to the underlying collection:

> An instance of the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` generic class is always read-only. A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper that prevents modifying the collection; **therefore, if changes are made to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those changes.**

---

Note: The constructor is required: C# does not allow field initializers to reference other instance fields, since [the compiler might rearrange the initialization order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14439262/87698). In VB.NET, where fields are initialized in the order in which they appear, this could be written as follows:

```
Private tagList As New List(Of String)()
Public ReadOnly Property Tags As IEnumerable(Of String) = New ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)(tagList)
```

Comment: You say no, but your suggested improvement says yes to me. ;) Of course it's not semantically identical, but for OP's specific case I think you could as well have said 'yes, like this'

Comment: @Joren: Even with the improvement, he still needs the explicit "backing field": `private IList<string> tags = new List<string>();` - we now have an explicit one *and* an implicit one. I have added the second line to my answer to emphasize this.

Comment: You're right, I guess I misunderstood the question.

Comment: This makes sense, and good spot re creating a new instance of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` each time the property is called. The only downside of the initialiser you put in your answer is it can only reference static members or constants, not instance variables; so I'm not sure how to offer up a single instance short of initialising the public `IEnumerable<T>` in a constructor.

Comment: @James: This took me by surprise, since both VB.NET and Java allow instance field references in field initializers. Well spotted, I have updated my answer.