# How do I avoid initializing an already initialized variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, field

```
namespace text_test
{
public class txt_program


{
    public class txt
    {

        /* 0 */
        int[] M_array_0 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 1 */
        int[] M_array_1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 2 */
        int[] M_array_2 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 3 */
        int[] M_array_3 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 4 */
        int[] M_array_4 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 5 */
        int[] M_array_5 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 6 */
        int[] M_array_6 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 7 */
        int[] M_array_7 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 8 */
        int[] M_array_8 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 9 */
        int[] M_array_9 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 10 */
        int[] M_array_10 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 11 */
        int[] M_array_11 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 12 */
        int[] M_array_12 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 13 */
        int[] M_array_13 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        int[][] M = { M_array_0, M_array_1 };

    }
}
```

}

An error appears associated with the section:

```
int[][] M = { M_array_0, M_array_1 };
```

The error concerns M_array_0 and M_array_1 in the above. What I dont understant is why I cant create a multidimensional array from the above. That code should I use? 
I tried:

```
string[][] M = { M_array_0, M_array_1 };
double[][] M = { M_array_0, M_array_1 };
```

The error reads:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'txt_program.txt.M_array_0'    text_test   \psf\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\text_test\text_test\text.cs    45  Active

On advance thank you.

Comment: You should set these variables in the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx).

Comment: If you make the arrays static this would work.

Comment: I've reopened the question since it looks more about jagged array creation than about the error ocurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to write a static method that returns the array that you want, and use that to assign the field:

```
public class txt
{
    private int[][] M = createArray();

    private static int[][] createArray()
    {
        /* 0 */
        int[] M_array_0 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 1 */
        int[] M_array_1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 2 */
        int[] M_array_2 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        /* 3 */

        // Etc

        return new [] { M_array_0, M_array_1, M_array_2 /* etc */ };
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can write it inline like so (but this is less flexible):

```
public class txt
{
    private int[][] M = 
    {
        new[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // M_array_0
        new[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // M_array_1
        new[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // M_array_3

        // Etc
    };
}
```

Since you are initialising all the arrays to the same size, and containing zeroes, you can shorten that to:

```
public class txt
{
    int[][] M = 
    {
        new int[14], // M_array_0
        new int[14], // M_array_1
        new int[14], // M_array_2

        // Etc
    };
}
```

However, I suspect that was just an example you gave, and in real code you would be using non-zero values.

Note also that you can declare `M` as readonly:

```
private readonly int[][] M = ...
```

which I recommend that you do, unless you need to change the array itself (rather than the contents) after the class instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

> A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property 'field' Instance fields cannot be used to initialize other
>   instance fields outside a method. If you are trying to initialize a
>   variable outside a method, consider performing the initialization
>   inside the class constructor

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5724t6za.aspx)

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property) for a descriptive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *Linq* in order to *generate* the array

```
int[][] M = Enumerable.Range(0, 13) // 13 rows
  .Select(x => new int[13])         // each line contains 13 items
  .ToArray();
```