# Assigning non-static data member variable with another variable

Tags: c#, class, variables, field, datamember

Why is it not possible to assign a class Non-static Data Member Variable with another Variable? 
For ex:

```
class A { 
   bool firstFlag=false; 
   bool secondFlag=firstFlag; // Showing Error.
   void SomeMethod(){} 
}
```

Comment: you could have it return a calculated value, i.e. secondFlag will always return the value stored in firstFlag, with syntax `bool secondFlag => firstFlag;`, but that's not the actual answer to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to the discussion on : [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)

Please refer The C# Language Specification Section 10.5.5.2 Instance Field Initialization states - A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference "this" in a variable initializer.( hence it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a simple-name).

Comment: In these instances, rather than write an answer, just click `close` under your question and mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is OOPS :-)

firstFlag & secondFlag both are Class DataMembers. By definition you can only access them in Member Methods or Constructors.

To do what you need - try this:

```
internal class A
{
   bool firstFlag = false, secondFlag = false;
}
```

Comment: You can assign a literal value and at the time the constructor is executed those values are assigned as default values.