# Is there a solution for this error for converting decimal to binary

Tags: c#, binary, decimal

I want to convert a decimal number (`int`) to a binary number and print it out.
My code in C# is this:

```
    int t1 = 2;
    public string test = Convert.ToString(t1, 2);
```

I get the error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property 'field'

I cannot find a solution for this :/

I found the solution: you have to declare t1 as static.
static int t1 works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)

Comment: Is this code in a class definition or method body? (it runs fine from a method body if you remove `public`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N9muSK)

Comment: this code is not in a method so far but I plan to implent it in one. Right now I want to try to it out if it works.

Comment: You'll save yourself time and effort if you start building the method right now

Answer (score 0):

Check this code,

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int static t1 = 2;
        string test = Convert.ToString(t1, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```

Thanks.