# How to call constructor with parameters?

Tags: c#

I have two classes and I need them to make instances of each other.
To preevent stack overflow exception I use constructors with parameters. But how can I call them? I can call only basic constructors.

```
public class TimerData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TimerData()
    {
        //parameters = new Parameters();
    }

    public TimerData(Parameters pr = null)
    {
        parameters = pr ?? new Parameters(this);
    }

    // Here I create an instance of the TimerData class to call the constructor 
    // with parameters through it. It gives an error that the field initializer 
    // cannot access a non-static field
    TimerData timerData = new TimerData();
    private Parameters parameters = new Parameters(timerData);
}


public class Parameters : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Parameters()
    {
        //timerData = new TimerData();
        //timerData.EventSecondsNotify += DecreaseFatigue;
        //timerData.EventSecondsNotify += DecreaseSatiety;
    }

    // How to call this constructor?
    public Parameters(TimerData td = null)
    {
        timerData = td ?? new TimerData(this);
        timerData.EventSecondsNotify += DecreaseFatigue;
        timerData.EventSecondsNotify += DecreaseSatiety;
    }

    private TimerData timerData;
}
```

Comment: I think this is your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property
"You cannot use an instance variable to initialize another instance variable. Why? Because the compiler can rearrange these - there is no guarantee that timerData will be initialized before parameters, so the above line might throw a NullReferenceException."

Comment: Do you really need the parameter-less constructor?

Comment: Even if you remove the issued line, this is still stack overflow, `TimerData` constructs itself infintely.

Comment: Consider also to avoid the ctor with Parameter par having a defalult value, you have the default parameterless ctor for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get why you are initializing the instances outside of your constructor. This should work fine:

```
public class TimerData
{
  private Parameters parameters;
  public TimerData(Parameters pr = null)
  {
    parameters = pr ?? new Parameters(this);
  }
}
public class Parameters
{
  private TimerData timerData;
  public Parameters(TimerData td = null)
  {
    timerData = td ?? new TimerData(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just forgot that I don't need constructor `Parameters()`  when I have `Parameters(TimerData td = null)`