# Random x and y position

Tags: c#, random

Only thing i want is to pick a random X position and random Y position

```
Random x = new Random(255);
Random y = new Random(255);
int xp = x.Next(0, 255);
int yp = y.Next(0,255);
```

compile time Error:

> Error:    CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Protivnik.x'
>
> Error: CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Protivnik.y'

Can anyone explain me why is this happening?

Comment: off-topic hint: you don't need 2 instances of Random class

Comment: if you use static method you will have to declare all member variable also static.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use that:

```
static class Program
{

  static Random random = new Random(255);

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int posX = random.Next(0, 255);
    int posY = random.Next(0, 255);
    ...
  }

}
```

Beware that Next upper bound is excluded, so here it generates [0..254].