# C# Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

Tags: c#

I have an interface Service which has a method GoTo

```
 public interface Service
 {
   bool GoTo(string NextPage , object parameter);
 }
```

I have a class A as follows

```
 public class A
 {
    private Service serviceA;

   //constructor of the class
   public A(Service serviceB, ServiceManager serviceManager)
   {
      this.serviceA = serviceB;
   }
   public ObservableCollection<SampleObject> Example { get; } = new 
   ObservableCollection<SampleObject>()
    {
        new SampleObject() { Action=  new DelegateCommand(() => this.serviceA.GoTo("NextPage", null)) 
    },
     
    };
```

}

I get an error on this saying that the keyword 'this' is not available in the current context. I have looked at [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property) and i can see that the error is due to the variable not being initialized in the constructor but in my case i do that . Any help in understanding this is better would be appreciated?

Comment: "but in my case i do that" - no you don't, you initialize the property at the point of its declaration. If you just changed your code to put `Example = new ObservableCollection<SampleObject>() { ... }` *in the constructor* it would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `this` in a property initializer. You can't do that. All you've got to do is move the initialization of `Example` from the point of declaration into the constructor body:

```cs
public class A
{
    private Service serviceA;
    public ObservableCollection<SampleObject> Example { get; }

    public A(Service serviceB, ServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceB;
        Example = new ObservableCollection<SampleObject>
        {
            new SampleObject
            {
                Action = new DelegateCommand(() => this.serviceA.GoTo("NextPage", null))
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`this` in this code `new SampleObject() { Action=  new DelegateCommand(() => this.serviceA.GoTo("NextPage", null))` is within the scope of `SampleObject`, not `A`.

Not the exact answer to your question but using **camelCase** for private field is a very bad practice, even though it's in the C# standard convention. A widely used convention in the .Net community is to name private field with leading underscore. For example: `private Service _serviceA;`

This convention helps avoid variable naming conflict like this situation and reduce human mistake on using global variables vs local variables.

Answer (score -2):

You can solve this problem by declaring a variable (e.g. `that`) to hold the value of `this`.  For example:

```
var that = this;
```

Then replace `this` with `that` in your existing code:

```
that.serviceA.GoTo("NextPage", null)
```

You would need to replace the property lambda for `Example` with a proper `get` block.  The first statement of the block should be `var` code above.

(This is a common technique in JavaScript, not because `this` is ever "unavailable", but rather because the context of `this` is not what you want it to be in the place you want to use it. But it can come in handy in C# too occasionally.)

Comment: Can you show how you would use this technique with the OP's code?

Comment: Didn't I post the code above?  Do I need to put the complete code?