# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property in EventHandler

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I'm getting the following error (A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property in EventHandler) on line:

```
FilesFound = FilesFound + 1;
```

Anyone know why and what would be the fix?

```
public class FileSearcher
{
    public event EventHandler<FileFoundArgs> FileFound;

    public int FilesFound { get; set; } = 0;
    
    EventHandler<FileFoundArgs> onFileFound = (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.FoundFile);
        FilesFound = FilesFound + 1;
    };
    
    public FileSearcher()
    {
        FileFound += onFileFound;
    }

    public void Search(string directory, string searchPattern)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, searchPattern))
        {
            FileFound?.Invoke(this, new FileFoundArgs(file));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says exactly what the problem is - your field initializer is using an instance member (`FilesFound`), via the lambda expression. You can't refer to other instance members within instance field initializers.

The simple fix is to move the initialization to the constructor:

```cs
private EventHandler<FileFoundArgs> onFileFound;

public FileSearcher()
{
    onFileFound = (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.FoundFile);
        FilesFound = FilesFound + 1;     
    };
    FileFound += onFileFound;
}
```

Or if you're not going to use `onFileFound` anywhere else, get rid of it as a field entirely, and just subscribe directly to the event in the constructor:

```cs
private EventHandler<FileFoundArgs> onFileFound;

public FileSearcher()
{
    FileFound += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.FoundFile);
        FilesFound = FilesFound + 1;     
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought if I had set the default value as 0, it should be accessible, but seems that's not the case.