# Problem creating an instance from inherited class, C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a Character class with a constructor that sets a name for character and a Weapon struct containing weapon name and damage in one file. I then created a Character child class, in another file, named Paladin, containing a Weapon type variable and the constructor inherited from Character class that sets a name for the character instance and creates a new Weapon instance. When I make a new Paladin type object, in another script file, using the base constructor, Unity Prints out a CS0103 error, telling me that the name I gave to the Weapon type variable doesn't exist in the current context.

I hit a huge solid brick wall. Please help. I tried everything I can think of.

**Character class:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character {

    public string characterName = "";
    public int characterExp = 0;

    public Character() {
        characterName = "Not assigned";
    }

    // CONSTRUCTOR SETTING A NEW NAME FOR THE CHARACTER INSTANCE
    public Character(string characterName) {
        this.characterName = characterName;
    }


    public virtual void PrintStatsInfo() {
        Debug.Log($"Character: {characterName} - {characterExp}.");
    }

    private void Reset() {
        this.characterName = "Not assigned";
        this.characterExp = 0;     
        }
}
```

**Weapon struct:**

```
public struct Weapon {
    
    public string name;
    public int damage;

    public Weapon(string name, int damage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public void PrintWeaponStats() {
        Debug.Log($"Weapon: {name} - {damage} DMB.");
    }
```

**Paladin class (character child):**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Paladin: Character {

    public Weapon weapon;

    //CONSTRUCTOR INHERITED FROM CHARACTER CLASS
    public Paladin(string characterName, Weapon weapon): base(characterName) {

        this.weapon = weapon;
    }


    public override void PrintStatsInfo() {

        Debug.Log($"Hey {characterName}, take your {weapon.name}");
    }
}
```

**Script file doing the other work:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LearningCurve : MonoBehaviour {

    
    //CREATING THE PALADIN INSTANCE USING THE BASE CONSTRUCTOR
    Paladin knight = new Paladin("Osip", sword);
    
    void Start() {
  
        knight.PrintStatsInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: So in the expression `new Paladin("Osip", sword)`, where do you expect the variable `sword` to come from? (Note that you haven't shown any such variable anywhere in the code - not even somewhat that you wouldn't be able to access it. It's just not there at all.)

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! [`[csharpscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/csharpscript/info)  is a CLR based scripting system which uses the C# programming language. This is not to be used for just any questions about `c#` ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I already tried to create a weapon type variable to pass into the constructor but Unity logged a cs0236 error, stating that "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ScriptFileName.sword' ".

Comment: Right, so you'd need to put the initialization code in a constructor, but still declare the fields outside the constructor. Did you try doing that? (It's always worth showing what you've tried in your question - so if you've tried creating an appropriate variable, please include that in the question...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create variable, before passing it down to constructor:

```
Weapon sword = new Weapon("Name", 1); // 1 as a damage
Paladin knight = new Paladin("Osip", sword);
```

Comment: I already created a variable to pass into the constructor as follows:


`Weapon sword = new Weapon("sword", 1);
    Paladin knight = new Paladin("Osip", sword);`


But Unity logged the error cs0236, stating "that A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ScriptFileName.sword' ".

Comment: @Strange.. It's not in the code Example you posted ... But this would make your question a duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property) .. why not simply create both instances in `Awake` or `Start` where you are not in a static environment anymore?

Comment: Just change var with `Weapon`, since you cant use var in field declarations

Comment: And @derHugo makes the right point, you should move it inside some method

Comment: @derHugo, you're right. I moved it inside Start and it is now fixed. Thanks for your help!