# Non-static class method can be added to Dictionary but not with collection initializer

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

The following code creates a dictionary with `Action`s.

```
class Test
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action> ActionLookup = new();

    public Test()
    {
        ActionLookup.Add("key", SampleAction);
    }

    protected virtual void SampleAction()
    {
        // Do something useful here...
    }
}
```

That code works. However, the following version gives me a compile error.

```
class Test
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action> ActionLookup = new()
    {
        ["key"] = SampleAction  // ERROR CS0236
    };

    protected virtual void SampleAction()
    {
        // Do something useful here...
    }
}
```

> Error CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Why can't I add `SampleAction` to my dictionary using a collection initializer when it's perfectly valid to add it manually?

I know I can workaround it using something like the following, but why is this necessary?

```
class Test
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action<MyClass>> ActionLookup = new()
    {
        ["key"] = o => o.SampleAction()
    };

    protected virtual void SampleAction()
    {
        // Do something useful here...
    }
}
```

*Note: It's not an option to make `SampleAction` static because I need it to be `virtual`.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property) Just put the whole initializer into the constructor of `Test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the context you are accessing the `SampleAction` changes. In the first code it is an instance method, in the second code it's field initializer.

There is one simple workaround which is turning `ActionLookup` into a property by using expression bodies (notice the `=>` instead of `=`):

```
private Dictionary<string, Action> ActionLookup => new()
{
    ["key"] = SampleAction  // ERROR CS0236
};
```

But, this will create the dictionary every time you access the property.

You can fix it by using a backing field for it:

```
private Dictionary<string, Action> _actionLookup;

private Dictionary<string, Action> ActionLookup
{
     get
     {
          if (_actionLookup != null)
          {
              _actionLookup = new Dictionary<string, Action>() { ["key"] = SampleAction };
          }

          return _actionLookup;
     }
}
```

I know a lot of workarounds going on here and your workaround may be simpler than this, but it's just another way to make it work. But I don't think it is worth just to get a simpler syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what the root difference is between an instance method being used to initialize a field and a field initializer. Why is it not still an instance method?

Comment: @JonathanWood you can check this answer that explains it in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57762805/3010968