# Converting string seperated by space to array in Blazor web server application

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I've been trying to solve this for the past 5 hours, but couldn't find any solution - please help me solve this problem.

This is my code:

```
@foreach (string title in titleList)  
{
    <span> @title</span>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string theTitle { get; set; }

    public static string[] titleList { get; set; } = theTitle.Split(", "); 
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'RelatedTopics.theTitle'

After I change to this:

```
[Parameter]
public static string theTitle { get; set; }
```

it still doesn't work in my application. Please help me with a solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean by still doesn't work? Are you getting the same error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)

Comment: Have you tried `public static string[] titleList {get; set; } = theTitle?.Split(", ") ?? Array.Empty<string>();` Maybe your parameter is empty at the beginning?

Comment: Hello Martin  , After I applied this it doesn't give error but when I apply this loop it doesn't give any result = @foreach (string title in titleList) { <a class="mylink" href="#" target="_blank"> <div class="mybtn m-3"><i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size:18px;"></i> <span style="font-size:18px"> &nbsp; @title</span></div></a> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use one instance variable to initialize another one using a field initializer. Instead put that code into `OnParametersSet` lifecycle method.

```
@foreach (string title in titleList)
{
    <span> @title</span>           
}

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string theTitle { get; set; }

    private string[] titleList = Array.Empty<string>();
   
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(theTitle))
        {
            titleList = theTitle.Split(", ");
        }
    }
}
```

If your string is space separated you should do `theTitle.Split(" ");` instead of `theTitle.Split(", ");`

Comment: After I applied this, I shows soo many errors please look at this :(  = https://prnt.sc/Th1wfZSkh-NM

Comment: A parenthesis was missing from the code I posted.. Updated my answer. Btw is there any reason you have `titleList` as static?

Comment: It is still throwing the error, it says it needs a return type = https://prnt.sc/zw5qoaROJ_mG

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: Current Code looks like this = https://prnt.sc/op7b_VeZJgZg

Comment: Also if the lenght of individual text is less then 3 then we don't include that text in our array, please help me with this.