# Member variable no initializing

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, initialization

I have started a new job and I need to write in vb.net

For the code I am writing, I need to map from an integer to a panel. I would like this mapping to have scope for the entire file, not just a single subroutine, so I have tried declaring it as such:

```
Private ReadOnly MAP = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Panel) From {
    {0, Nothing},
    {1, Foo},
    {2, Bar},
    ...
}
```

Then, I have a subroutine something like this (simplified)

```
Private Sub Thing(ID As Integer)
    If MAP.Item(ID) IsNot Nothing
        MAP.Item(ID).Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

and let say I call `Thing(1)`, that should make `Foo` visible, but instead nothing happens. If I `Dim MAP` *inside* of `Thing`, it works as expected. I obviously don't want to be constructing my map everytime I call the sub though, as that kinda defeats the purpose of a map by adding the overhead of constructing it at every use (although it is more readable).

Basically what I'm wondering is why the construction of `MAP` doesn't remain when I use it? Shouldn't all member variables be constructed before we begin executing any of the methods of a class, if declared in this way?

Comment: I think the most likely cause of the problem is that `Foo` and `Bar` in the context of the initialization aren't the same as what you would get in the context of the routine, but you've cut the example down so much it's impossible to be sure.  Can you get this closer to a [mcve]?

Comment: If the issue was that `MAP` wasn't constructed (or filled), you would get exceptions, either `NullReferenceException` or `KeyNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is here is Forms are classes, which have a defined initialization order where fields (like `MAP`) are initialized *before* the constructor runs. This makes sense. If you have a complex constructor, you would want and expect to be able to use defined field values there.

However, form controls are initialized in the `InitializeComponent()` method called at the end of the constructor. Therefore, at the time the `MAP` variable is initialized, the `Foo` and `Bar` member variables exist, but they are not yet initialized to refer to the actual control objects they are intended to represent.

To fix this, you need to change the code so items are added to the `MAP` collection *after* the `InitializeComponent()` method runs.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :) Just couldn't find any documentation on the initialization order. Thanks

Comment: @user21749640 And you won't. For some reason this is not well defined in the VB.Net language spec like it is for C#... but it **IS** what happens, and mostly follows the defined C# order.

Comment: But since `Foo` and `Bar` are panels, so reference types, they should refer to the actual panels at the time OP is trying to use `Thing`, assuming that it's not in the constructor or `InitializeComponent` method. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `MAP` will get a copy of the references in `Foo` and `Bar` at the time it is initialized. Once that is done, changes to `Foo` and `Bar` no longer matter.

Comment: In C# it's [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property), i guess because of this confusion here. The error in C# is clear and makes sense. Why would you want to intialize something like the dictionary with something else that might not yet be initialied(the panels). This would work by accident or not, depending on the order of initialization.