# Using private static members across partial classes

Tags: c#, static-members, partial-classes

I have partial classes with static readonly fields, and in one of the partial classes I'm creating a static readonly list of all the static readonly members. For some reason, the list ends up with the correct numbers of entries, but all the entries all null.

```
public partial class Numbers
{
    public static readonly List<string> All = new List<string>
    {
        One,
        Two
    };
}

public partial class Numbers
{
    public static readonly string One = "One";
}

public partial class Numbers
{
    public static readonly string Two = "Two";
}

var all = Numbers.All;

// all.Count() is 2
// all.First() is null
// all.Last() is null
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is?

I've noticed that if I change the `Numbers.All` field to be a non-readonly property, the values within the list are as expected, not null. So I'm guessing this is something to do with how the partial classes are read, or something to do with the readonly usage, but I'm really thrown by this.

Switching to a non-readonly property is obviously easily done, and maybe that's a better approach(?), but I'm really curious why using readonly fields doesnt work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialization Order of Static Fields in Static Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494735/initialization-order-of-static-fields-in-static-class) Note by the way, your problem is nothing directly to do with `readonly`

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I think this explains the issue I'm seeing. So what I'm taking away from this is, use a static constructor to ensure the static members are initialised *before* the constructor is executed.

Comment: Indeed, a static constructor is the solution..

Comment: @Orace Yes that's really helpful, I didnt realise that using partial classes would have such an impact. Thanks